# How to get the line no or file name of js errors?

Tags: javascript

I am getting a bit tired of errors like these:

[image]

It says nothing about what file or what function or what line.

In this case this was the caller line

```
vm.setDates(new Date(vm.checkin*1000).format('M d Y'), new Date(vm.checkout*1000).format('M d Y'))
```

And a few functions down in the code was the .format function where the error was..

Is there any way to get better "error directions" than app.bundle.js:12345 ??

Comment: I think you should take a look at the concept of [Source Maps](https://trackjs.com/blog/debugging-with-sourcemaps/)

Comment: is there 'substr' string in your program?

Comment: There will be name and line number of the file on right hand side of this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use sourcemaps. A sourcemap is a mapping between the generated/transpiled/minified JavaScript file and one or more original source files. The main purpose of sourcemaps is to aid debugging. Basically, if there’s an error in the generated code file, the map can tell you the original source file location. Reference: [Sourcemaps](https://trackjs.com/blog/debugging-with-sourcemaps/).

Comment: Thanks Eduado!! - my webpack already had something like this, but I dont understand what this is?  `var ENV = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;
var isTest = ENV === 'test' || ENV === 'test-watch';
var isProd = ENV === 'build';`